# Ubuntu Startup Disk/USB problem

Tags: 12.04, installation

Here is the problem.
I burned a Ubuntu Installation disk and ubuntu usb.
I used Ubuntu 12.04 amd64.
My computer is 64bit.

Here is what happens:
When computer starts, it boots from the usb properly.
Displays the menu, but when I click either install or just run Ubuntu without installation I face black screen and nothing happens.
The same happens when I boot from Ubuntu disk. I tried reinstalling usb, nothing changed.

Any help is highly appreciated.
I really want to escape Windows 8.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Have you already tried to make a usb pen-boot with yumi? Here's the download site and a tutorial http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/

Comment: I haven't. I used UnetBootin.
Shouldn't it work though?

Because it boots, it just doesn't open the options.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the windows usb creator [Here](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/downloads/YUMI/YUMI-0.1.0.7.exe), this works in windows, and will create a USB for you, will also download the image.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu documentation advise to [download the installer](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) and then if you want to try on USB you should see [this](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/try-ubuntu-before-you-install) article.

Answer (score 0):

## Try to select compatibility options

After booting on your USB drive or CDRom, choose the correct language, and try to check inside the **F6** Menu : **acpi=off** OR **noapic**.

*Check [BootOption](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions#Ubuntu_CD_Advanced_Welcome_Page_Options) for more informations.*

If this isn't working, please detail your hardware here.